# Finding the Balance - Income vs Expenditure

Tags: game-mechanics, balance, economy

I'm working on a game idea that uses an in-game currency, and basic business (income/outcome).

Basically, a certain type of building will generate 'income' per seconds until it hits a certain capacity (per building).

There are many different types of buildings, each with their own 'rate', 'income' and 'capacity', as well as 'cost to purchase building' in the first place.

I want to know if there is a good tactic, or strategy on how to balance this out? I don't want to make the purchasing of the buildings too easy - so the user has to only wait a few seconds ... thats pointless.

And on top of that - each building can be upgraded, which basically increases the 'rate', 'amount' and 'capacity' - with each upgrade increasingly getting more expensive - however this is relative as the user is now getting more cash flow.

Thanks.

Comment: though more related to clicker games, [this article](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/articles/numbers-getting-bigger-the-design-and-math-of-incremental-games--cms-24023) by tuts plus is perhaps a good start. Showing costs, exponential growth etc.

Comment: Thanks @lozzajp - this was a very helpful read. I know understand what is required, and what my genre game is called! Yay

Answer (score 3):

Incremental games (not sure if you are making one) make use of a multiplication factor between building upgrades. The ideal factor is within `1.07 and 1.14` for these games. So if you pay 10 for the first building/level you pay `10 * 1.14` for the 2nd upgrade and `10 * 1.14^21` for the 20th building/upgrade. This creates a curve and eventually it takes a long time before you can upgrade. To help out you can add some extra perks after X levels to level things out and give the game some more depth as well.

[Cookie clicker docs](http://cookieclicker.wikia.com/wiki/Building) give some nice insight into these numbers. I also advice to use spreadsheets to work out the numbers and balance your game further.

Comment: Would it make sense to have a different 'multiplier' for each building type?

Comment: Yes! The higher the multiplier the faster the curve goes up so it takes longer to upgrade. You might have to normalise this a bit earlier then lower multipliers with some bonus effects or it takes just too long. But different multipliers do add a little variation in guess.

Answer (score 1):

Make subsequent upgrades much more expensive with smaller upgrades, for example:

1. Juice Stall - 60 coins - 1 coin / second
2. Vending Machine - 360 coins - 3 coins / second
3. Coffee Vendor - 1080 coins - 5 coins / second
4. Charity Store - (`nc^2 where n is number of buildings and c is the total CPS output of those buildings`) coins -  Upgrades the output of all buildings by 1 coin / second.
5. Fast Food Chain - 12800 coins - 12 coins / second
6. ...

Answer (score 1):

Every game is different, so there is no golden hammer solution. But there are a few key concepts which usually show up in every game.

### Amortization Time

When an investment generates income, it will have amortized itself sooner or later. You need to take this into account to avoid any investments from either being pointless (it won't amortize before the player completed/quit the game) or a complete no-brainer (will amortize almost immediately). When an investment generates the same resource which it costs, that's trivial to calculate: `Cost / production = amortization time`.

But it gets more complex when you have multiple resources. In that case you need to figure out the relative values of your different resources. For example, when a quarry costs 100 stone and 200 wood, and wood is twice as valuable to the player as stone, the actual cost is equivalent to 500 stone. Note that when you don't have a straightforward way to convert one resource into another, then the values of different resources can be hard to estimate. It might take a lot of testplaying to figure out if experienced players will *really* find 100 wood as valuable as 50 stone and vice versa.

### Income Growth Curve

In many economical games, the income of the player will steadily increase. That will make investments which seem ridiculously high at the start to look like spare-change in the late-game. It is important to understand how the player's income will grow over the course of your game. Ideally you should figure out a formula to calculate how much income the player should have at what stage of the game. You can then regulate your prices according to that formula.

### Diminishing Returns

This is a method to suppress income growth: The amortization time of every further upgrade to an investment should increase. This can be done by making each upgrade level more expensive, less effective or both. When you don't do that, each upgrade will take less time to achieve than the last one. At some point the player will earn resources faster than they can hammer the upgrade-button, which usually doesn't make for a very interesting game experience.